# centering a galleria (Javascript/Jquery) issue

Tags: html, galleria

Currently i got this piece of code when it comes to centering

```
#galleria{
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #000;
```

However, i wanted the galleria to be shown in the middle, it just shows at the right corner, i use jquery, and the galleria from www.galleria.io however i just can't center the galleria, is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it would be in the right corner with out floating it...

Anyways, you should add `margin: 0 auto;` to the css like:

```
#galleria{
   width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: #000;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Make sure that it's container has a width set as well.